# TabularDataBunch.from_df giving error with no attribute 'codes'

Tags: python, fast-ai

I am having problems using the fastai tabular data, so I tried to do the simplest thing which is to fit a polynomial. However, when I create a data bunch, I am getting the error

```
~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastai/tabular/data.py in get(self, o)
    119 
    120     def get(self, o):
--> 121         codes = [] if self.codes is None else self.codes[o]
    122         conts = [] if self.conts is None else self.conts[o]
    123         return self._item_cls(codes, conts, self.classes, self.col_names)

AttributeError: 'TabularList' object has no attribute 'codes'
```

fastai version 1.0.27

Here is the code that causes the error:

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.tabular import * 
import os

# generate some polynomial to test the functions out
x = np.arange(0, 1000)
y = x^2 + 1

# some fastai variables
path = os.getcwd()
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
dep_var = 'y'
cat_names = []
procs = [Normalize]
valid_idx = range(1,1000)

# get the data bunch
data = TabularDataBunch.from_df(path, df, dep_var, valid_idx=valid_idx, procs=procs) # this line causes the error above
```

I tried the code from the [overview](https://docs.fast.ai/tabular.html) page of tabular data, it works, but when I tried it on my own data, the problem above occurred.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error with tabular data as well. I see your valid range is the entire dataset -- were you getting other fastai.tabular errors with smaller valid_idx ranges?